# web.py: passing initialization / global variables to handler classes?

Tags: python, web.py

I'm attempting to use web.py with Tokyo Cabinet / pytc and need to pass the db handle (the connection to tokyo cabinet) to my handler classes so they can talk to tokyo cabinet.

Is there a way to pass the handler to the handler class's **init** function? Or should I be putting the handle in globals() ? What is globals() and how do you use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would be to add a load hook (described [here](http://webpy.org/cookbook/sqlalchemy) for sqlalchemy). Define a function that connects to Tokyo Cabinet and adds the resulting db object as an .orm attribute to web.ctx, which is always available inside the controller.